# css animation opening cube's opening

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

In my project, when the homepage is opened, it should run a CSS animation so that the cube's faces open. After the animation is complete the faces should remain.
So I need to modify this code, because as it is the faces open and then  close. After they open the faces should remain on the screen instead of closing.

How can I do this?

```css
.sk-folding-cube {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s 1 linear both;
  animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s 1 linear both;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube5 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(360deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube5 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(360deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube5:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube6:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Open Cube</title>
  <h1>Apertura Cubo</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sk-folding-cube">
    <div class="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
    <div class="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
    <div class="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
    <div class="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
    <div class="sk-cube5 sk-cube"></div>
    <div class="sk-cube6 sk-cube"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```